# How to get jnlp href attribute at run time in Java web Start app (similar to BasicService.getCodeBase())?

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I have a single application that I am deploying via Java web Start.  I have several different jnlp files for different launch scenarios.  I am using DownloadService2 to check for updates periodically.  When an update is available, I prompt the user.  If they elect to update, I launch a new instance of [javaws using Runtime.getRuntime().exec()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/javaws.html), passing in the full jnlp url, then I System.exit(0).  Effectively, this kicks off an update/restart cycle.

The problem is, since I could have started from one of several jnlp files, I can't simply hardcode the url.  I know that I can get the host:port portion of the url from [BasicService.getCodeBase()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/BasicService.html#getCodeBase()), but is there a way to get the file portion of the url?  Currently I am adding a "jnlp" argument to the application-desc similar to the following so that I can retrieve it from args:

```
<application-desc main-class="my.main.class">
<argument>jnlp=myjnlp.jnlp</argument>
<application-desc/>
```

I think this will work, but I'm wondering if I am making it harder than it needs to be.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this issue using the approach described in my question.  There doesn't seem to be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be best to provide this functionality using the [DownloadService](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/javawebstart/1.0.1/javadoc/javax/jnlp/DownloadService.html).

Comment: I was aware of the DownloadService class, but I'm not sure how I can use it to get the name of the jnlp file for the currently running application.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: My apologies.  I had misread the question and the DS will not solve the stated problem.  :(